# How to display text in a DataGridViewCell that represents an instance of a class

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable.
One of the columns of the DataTable is of Type IMessages

```
DataTable source = _applicationManager.Retrieve(); // Populate DataTable
source.Columns.Add("Messages", typeof(IMessages));
dataGridView.DataSource = source;
```

IMessages interface:

```
interface IMessages : IEnumerable<IMessage>
{
    string GetMessages { get; }
    string ToString();
}
```

Messages class:

```
class Messages : IMessages
{
     /* This code is less relevant, here just to show you the entire picture
     private List<IMessage> _messagesList;         
     public string GetMessages
     {
        get
        {
            var messages = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (IMessage message in _messagesList)
            {
                messages.AppendLine(message.ToString());
            }

            return messages.ToString();
        }
     }
     ***********************************/

     public override string ToString()
     {
        return "warning";   // TODO            
     }
}
```

DataGridView Event:

```
private void dataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{                   
    var messages = _applicationManager.GetMessages() as IMessages;
    if (messages.Any())
    {
        dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Messages"].Value = messages;
    }
 }

private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var messages = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Messages"].Value as    IMessages;
    if (messages != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(messages.GetMessages, "Messages", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the DataGridView does not display "warning" word in the cell, the link is working fine but the cell is blank.
I thought that overriding ToString() in Messages class will make it but it doesn't.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

If I am getting rid of the IMessages interface and dealing with Messages instance, the ToString() overridden method is fetch and the "warning" text is displayed in the cell.

When calling this following line, ToString() method is called. But when the cell is bound to an Interface, ToString() method is not called.

```
dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Messages"].Value = messages;
```

In order to make it work without getting rid of the Interface, I called ToString() method during cell formatting event of the DataGridView:

```
private void PODetailsDGV_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1) return;

        if (e.Value != null && dataGridView.Columns["Messages"].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            e.Value = e.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather adding the value in the `RowsAdded` event handler, add directly in the source i.e. `DataTable`

```
DataTable source = _applicationManager.Retrieve(); // Populate DataTable
source.Columns.Add("Messages", typeof(IMessages));
// ------- changed code ------------------
// this is just an example, you can also place a loop here
// and iterate through all the lines in the DataTable and set the object
// in the "Messages" column
source.Rows[0]["Messages"] = messageobject; 
// --------------------------------------------------
dataGridView.DataSource = source;
```

The reason why it is NOT showing could be, because `DataGridView` control is bound with a `DataSource` while you are trying to set value in the grid control's cell which it is right now ignoring because it is reading value from source which is `DataTable` and right now `DataTable` don't have the Message object in any row. This is my assumption I could be wrong.